# How can I parameterize the tablename in a CREATE TABLE expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, create-table

I was wondering if syntax exist to express something like the following:

```
DECLARE @MyTableNameVARCHAR(50)
SET @MyTableName= 'AccountSummary'

CREATE TABLE dbo.@MyTableName
(
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    AccountId int NOT NULL
    Amount real
)
```

Obviously, the above is not working. I made my scripts working with `EXEC`, but it seems rather convoluted. Can I use `CREATE TABLE` with a parameter for the tablename?

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL, that is, generate the SQL as a string and run `sp_executesql`.

Comment: @Gordon: that's similar to using `EXEC` in transact-sql. If that's the only way to do this, then I have to stick to my current practice.

Comment: @Abel It's exactly the same :) Remember this rule: the *schema* of SQL statements must be *fixed* when they are parsed (EXEC defers this step). This is the general reason why variables/data cannot be used as table or column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyTableName NVARCHAR(50);
SET     @MyTableName = 'AccountSummary';

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql =  N'CREATE TABLE '+ QUOTENAME(@MyTableName) + N'
            (
                Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
                AccountId int NOT NULL,
                Amount REAL
            )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

**OR**

```
DECLARE @MyTableName NVARCHAR(50);
SET     @MyTableName = 'AccountSummary';

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql =  N'CREATE TABLE [@MyTableName]
            (
                Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
                AccountId int NOT NULL,
                Amount real
            )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@MyTableName NVARCHAR(50)'
                     ,@MyTableName
```

Comment: While this is actually what I am doing right now, I hoped for an alternative solution. But @user2864740 explained already above why this is a limitation. Guess it is not possible without string concatenating the DDL. _(both this and Karl's answer are valid answers, but I find yours more complete and directly applicable, tx)_

Comment: My proposed method is safe and prevents you against a possible sql injection attack, When concatenating string and using `EXEC('Sql String')`  that way is less secure and open for injection attacks.

Comment: Good points, though for a locally-run one-off script I am not that worried for SQL-injection ;) (and I try to refrain from using hand-made string-concat-style SQL in applications).

Comment: Only thing you should ever concatenate is object names and make sure you use `QUOTENAME()` function which puts square brackets around the passed variable and forces sql server to treat it as an object name.

Answer (score 2):

"Can I use CREATE TABLE with a parameter for the tablename?"

No. You have to use dynamic SQL as you indicate you already have working.

This sort of thing is convoluted by nature.

Depending on what you are actually doing you might feel better about having a app layer constrcut the DDL, rather than doing it all in TSQL.

Comment: Well, I would, normally. But I just needed a one-off conversion script from SQLite to MS SQL Server and needed a few table-corrections afterwards that are almost the same for all tables. Parameterization would have helped making these one-off scripts less error-prone.

Comment: When i have a one off thingy like this I often use Excel to create all the SQL.